# Redirect all pages to a new domain htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, server, http-status-code-301, permanent

I want to redirect my entire website to a new unique address/domain without respecting the relation between filenames.

I don't want `olddomain.com/foo.html` to be redirected to `newdomain.com/foo.html`.

I want this result with a htaccess file:

```
olddomain.com/foo.html => newdomain.com
olddomain.com/foo/bar.html => newdomain.com
olddomain.com/a/b/c/moo.html => newdomain.com
```

The `Redirect 301` function of htaccess does exactly what I don't want.

How I can proceed?

***Answer to the RavinderSingh13's comment:***

This is what I tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And :

```
Redirect 301 / https://www.newdomain.com/
```

And also :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.comfr$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.newdomain\.com/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer by reviewing my question:

I just had to remove the **$1** at the end as it's a regular expression, it contains the value of the reference script name.

So the working solution for me is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `^(.*)$` - there's no need to capture the URL-path if this is not being used. A mod_alias `RedirectMatch 301 ^ https://www.newdomain.com/` is arguably simpler.